# Collect all the values from CHECKED checkboxes with the same ID/Name

Tags: jquery

```
$('[name="checks"]:checked').each(function (e) {            
            //I can access the checked checkboxes. But...
            CheckboxId += this.checkboxID;//I want each checkbox ID here

        });
```

all checkboxes `name="checks"`, `value="..."` and `id="chk"`. How can I get the checked checkboxes value? Cause all I need is values. and they are only different.

Comment: Give each one a unique name/id. If they are in the same div you can get all checkboxes in that div.

Comment: I cannot give them, Cause they are auto generated

Comment: Can you explain your problem again. you are trying to collect all the values  from checkboxes with the same ID/Name ?

Comment: Collect all the values from CHECKED checkboxes with the same ID/Name. Yes

Comment: do you want to make object that has the ID/name and the comulated value ? or its the same Name / id for all ?

Comment: I need to get the values at a time and send them to server side. If I can get all the required values as csv/ list/ array, that will be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell me if this is what you're looking for:

```
var checkboxes = {};
$('[name="checks"]:checked').each(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    checkboxes[id] = $(this).val();

    // or if you want to accumulate the val to id
    //checkboxes[id] = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: As, there ID is same `chk`, so the id will return same. And, no. I m not looking for this

Comment: the ideas of all the checkboxes is the same ? is the value the same also or it servse as id ?

Comment: hey, Wait a sec, var id = $(this).attr('`value`'); I changed the line a little bit. and it worked :)) Thanks buddy, correct ur answere and i will accept it.

Comment: well you dont need attr value you can use val(), but glat it works

Comment: I have used val(), but that returned the value according to attr('id')

Comment: So now that you have attr('value') what are you going to do with it ?

Comment: i will conctatenate them in a var & send them to server :))) OR the array u suggested.

Comment: but, I think attr('id') is not correct. So can you please change it?

Comment: change to value like you did